# Not able to download Google AdWords report using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, report, google-ads-api

I am developing a net console application for downloading adwords reports.
It is work perfectly fine for facebook reports.
But when I am doing the same with GDN, Google AdWords' csv file is downloaded in HTM format with no actual data.
My Ruby code is:

```
link='link url in scheduled report'
GDN_Form = page.forms[0]
GDN_Form.Email ='LOGIN ID'
GDN_Form.Passwd = 'PASSWORD'
puts "Redirecting to Page"
#puts page.to_html

#Subitting the login Page
GDN_Form.add_field! 'send','Submit'
page = agent.submit(GDN_Form, GDN_Form.buttons[0])
agent.get(link)
page2 = agent.get(link)
puts page2.title
agent.get(link).save('C:\Ruby21\DownloadedeReports\ClientName.CSV')
```

The file is downloaded, but actual data is not downloaded.

I have to to do this task without using Google APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google login procedure has changed, first you need to find login url which it comes with _ga cookie id which is dynamically changed.
Here is the e.g.

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=adwords&continue=https://adwords.google.com/um/identity?sourceid=awo&subid=in-ww-di-awhp&hl=en_IN&_ga=1.229603486.307864125.1437111208&hl=en_IN&ltmpl=signin&passive=0&skipvpage=true#identifier

and login page contains email id which you have to find using mechanize then click on the next, same you have to do with password. After submit click on your schedule report url.